# How to compare data in two rows of Google Sheets and output number of cells in row 1 that are > the cell in row 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

For example, given

1|  2  3  2  5

2|  4  2  2  3

I want to be COMPARE(row1,row2) and return 2, or COMPARE(row2,row1) and return 1. I'm trying to create a custom function in JavaScript, here's what I have so far:

```
function COMPARE(row1,row2) {
  var total=0; var i=0;
  if (row1.map){
    for (i;i<11;i++); {
      if (row1[i]>row2[i]){
      total=total+1; 
      } 
    }
  }
return total;
}
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with the cell referencing, but I'm not sure. Thanks for any help.

Comment: My big question is what makes the values `1` and `2` when given those two inputs? Also, though much less important, why are you grabbing the `length` of row1 and then hard coding `11` into your `for` loop?

Comment: When I COMPARE(row1,row2) I'm asking for the number of cells in row 1 that exceed the cell in the same column of row 2. The second column and fourth column of row 1 exceed the respective row 2 values. So the return would be 2.

I was playing around trying to find my error, which is why I am still grabbing row1.length, I forgot to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only "bug" you are running into is accessing your areas starting from `1`. Arrays in JavaScript are `0` based. Assuming you didn't address the other aspects of your code this should work:

```
function COMPARE(row1,row2) {
  var total=0; var len=row1.length; var i=0;
  if (row1.map){
    for (i;i<11;i++); {
      if (row1[i]>row2[i]){
        total=total+1; 
      } 
    }
  }
  return total;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. When I type COMPARE('range','range') into my sheet, the cell is blank